# Python 3: How to shorten list of "if" and "elif" statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I need help or an explanation as to how I would shorten this code?

I thought about just combining the two, but when I tried, I just keep getting errors

Any ideas?

Thank You!

```
import random

fave_word = 'hello' + "world"

rand_num = random.randint(0,3)

if rand_num == 0:
    fave_word += ''

elif rand_num == 1:
    fave_word += 'Bob'
elif rand_num == 2:
    fave_word += 'BobBob'
elif rand_num == 3:
    fave_word += 'BobBobBob'
else:
    fave_word += ''
print(fave_word)

fave_word_2 = 'csc108' + "world"
if rand_num == 0:
    fave_word_2 += ''
elif rand_num == 1:
    fave_word_2 += 'Bob'
elif rand_num == 2:
    fave_word_2 += 'BobBob'
elif rand_num == 3:
    fave_word_2 += 'BobBobBob'
else:
    fave_word_2 += ''
print(fave_word_2)
```

Comment: use a dictionary to add the text according to the index.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you want to repeat "Bob" `rand_num` times. You can do it like this:

```
import random

fave_word = 'hello' + "world"

rand_num = random.randint(0,3)
fave_word += rand_num * "Bob"
print(fave_word)
```

This will print

```
helloworldBob
```

if `rand_num` is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list & indices.

Like: 

`words = ['', 'Bob', 'BobBob', 'BobBobBob']
fave_word += words[rand_num]`

We do not have much detail about the logic behind and this look quite dummy data so can't say much...